# Implementing UTFGRID with MapServer and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, mapserver

I'm having troubles using utfgrid module with openlayers. The implementation on Mapserver's side is quite simple, even if i have doubts about the imagetype :

```
MAP
    IMAGETYPE   UTFGRID
    SIZE        2000 2000
    CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/ms4w/tmp/ms_error.txt"
    #DEBUG 4
    EXTENT -176.197 -31.0869 181.47 81.8381
    NAME "allexmaple"

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END 
    QUERYMAP
        STATUS ON
    END
    OUTPUTFORMAT
        NAME "utfgrid"
        DRIVER UTFGRID
        MIMETYPE "application/json"
        EXTENSION "json"
        FORMATOPTION "UTFRESOLUTION=4"
        FORMATOPTION "DUPLICATES=false"
    END
    WEB
        IMAGEPATH "tmp/"
        IMAGEURL "tmp/"
    END
    SYMBOL
        NAME "mysymbol"
        TYPE pixmap
        ANCHORPOINT 0.5 0.5
        IMAGE  "icons/mysymbol.png"
    END 

    LAYER
        TOLERANCE 10
        CONNECTIONTYPE postgis 
        NAME "example"
        CONNECTION "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=ais_data user=postgres password=admin port=5432"
        DATA "geom from mytable using srid=4326"
        STATUS ON
        TYPE POINT
        UTFITEM   "id"
        UTFDATA   "{\"id\":\"[id]\",\"name\":\"[name]\"}"
        TEMPLATE 'query.html'
        HEADER 'header.html'
        FOOTER 'footer.html'
        CLASSITEM "ct"

        CLASS
            EXPRESSION "mysymbol"
            STYLE
                ANGLE [angle]
                SYMBOL 'mysymbol' 
            END # style 
        END # class 
    END
END
```

Openlayers, on the other hand, doesn't have an efficient example. I don't know what to provide in my URL. Here's what I tried:

```
var gridSource = new ol.source.TileUTFGrid({
       url: 'http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&layers=example&tiled=true&mode=map&type=utfgrid&format=application/json'
      });
 var mySuperLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
           source: gridSource
      });
```

But nothing appears and my URL stays in pending until timeout

Comment: have you checked the log file for mapserver ?

Comment: @Shiko Actually I thought the tileJson was generated by mapserver. Now I have a tileJson but still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ol.source.TileUTFGrid` is layer source for UTFGrid interaction data loaded from TileJSON format. `url` option of `TileUTFGrid` should point to json with data in [TileJSON](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec) format. In your case it can be simple `tile.json` file created manually:

```
{
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "tiles": [
        "http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&layers=example&mode=tile&tile={x}+{y}+{z}&tilemode=gmap&map.imagetype=png"
    ],
    "grids": [
        "http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&layers=example&mode=tile&tile={x}+{y}+{z}&tilemode=gmap&map.imagetype=utfgrid"
     ]
}
```

Don't forget add to mapfile the following section:

```
OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME          "png"
    EXTENSION     "png"
    MIMETYPE      "image/png"
    DRIVER         AGG/PNG
    IMAGEMODE      RGBA
    FORMATOPTION  "INTERLACE=OFF"
END
```

Connect it to OpenLayers (don't forget to modify view options and path to json file):

```
var mapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/tile.json"
    })
});

var gridSource = new ol.source.TileUTFGrid({
    url: "http://localhost:5000/tile.json"
});

var gridLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: gridSource});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [mapLayer, gridLayer],
    target: "map",
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [9449777.3, 6914882.51],
        zoom: 7
    });
});

map.on("click", function(evt) {
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();

    gridSource.forDataAtCoordinateAndResolution(evt.coordinate, viewResolution,
        function (data) { console.log(data); }
    );
});
```

It looks like UTFGrid doesn't work in Windows, see [#5432](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/pull/5342). In Linux all works fine in my case.

Comment: I could start by creating the tileJSON first... haha thank you for your answer, as soon as #5432 is solved I'll give it a try

Comment: Are you faced with the same issue?

Comment: I can't tell as I have to create a tile JSON first. At the time I'm trying to finish my version without utfgrid, but requests to the server via getGetFeatureInfoUrl are not as quick as expected (like 2 seconds) so that's why I'll go to utfGrid after.

Comment: Ok so if I had what you wrote, it gives me "Unable to select IMAGETYPE `utfgrid'." . If I change the output format like it's specified in [mapserver](http://mapserver.org/output/utfgrid_output.html) I get a strange utfgrid http://imgur.com/a/MxGGD

Comment: You don't have to replace "utfgrid" OUTPUTFORMAT section with "png". You should have them both in mapfile.

Comment: Oh, ok ! Sorry. I still have the strange utfgrid though, my guess is that this comes from postgis, do you work with postgis for your example?

Comment: Here is my mapfile (PostGIS instance is public accessible so you can to try it): http://pastebin.com/8UrvL0w8

Answer (score 2):

More an addition to @drnextgis than a complete answer to your question.

To avoid creating a `tile.json` file, you can replace the:

```
var gridSource = new ol.source.TileUTFGrid({
  url: "http://localhost:5000/tile.json"
});
```

with:

```
var gridSource = new ol.source.TileUTFGrid({
  tileJSON: {
    "version": "2.1.0",
    "grids": [
      "http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&layers=example&mode=tile&tile={x}+{y}+{z}&tilemode=gmap&map.imagetype=utfgrid"
    ]
  }
});
```

It's due to addition for supporting GeoServer more easily, without an intermediate file (See this PR for details https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/5120)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm kind of new in Mapserver's world, it's nice to have good habits from the start :) actually I can't make my utfgrid due to #5432 like @drnextgis said. So... another time !